# How to auto-import default React classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auto-import, react-typescript

I've installed a fresh React Application with Typescript as follows:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

when I ran the app, everything seemed fine. So I removed the generated code and started writing my own.

When I started typing, I noticed that my IDEs (Webstorm and VS Code) doesn't automatically import default classes such as `React`:

[image: can't auto-import default react classes]

As you can see in the following example, when I selected `React`, nothing happened. But when I selected `Component` (which in't exported as default), it has been imported.

After that, I installed  `"@material-ui/core": "^4.6.0"`.

And it seems that I get the same behavior in here too. Now, I can tolerate using snippers such as `imr` in order to automatically import it. But as an Angular fan, I'm not used to manually import everything and I'm hoping that there's a solution for this.

Which leads me to the following question:

Instead of manually importing every module I'm going to use, is there an easier way to do so? it starts to be very painful.

I have already tried the following solutions:

1. Installing [steoates' Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport)
2. Installing [Arnuariri's Material UI Snippets](https://github.com/tmarun/vscode-material-ui-snippets)
3. Installing [Burke's Simple React Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=burkeholland.simple-react-snippets)

*I'm not looking for a snippet extension, I'm looking for a way to automatically import default exported modules.*

Comment: try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.ReactSnippets

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I'm not looking for snippets, I'm looking for a way to automatically import modules while I code

Comment: Have you played around with the auto import settings in webstorm?  You can also get a popup if you type what you want and then command/click the unknown component to bring up the import menu.

Comment: @JakeLuby not sure I understood your meaning

Answer (score -2):

you have to install Auto import (VSCode extensions)

Link:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import

> Automatically finds, parses and provides code actions and code completion for all available imports. Works with JavaScript and TypeScript.